# Calling string from another sub

Tags: vb.net, string, function

I want to use a string that I declared previously into a function (there's a reason why I want it to be a function). But the function isn't recognising the string, my question is how I could modify the code below to make it work? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
Sub encryption

Dim text As String = wraper.DecryptData(ciphertext)

End sub
```

and...

```
Public Function CallResults() As String

Dim instructions As String = text '//'text' isn't being recognised
Return instructions

End function
```

Comment: are they both in the same class?

Comment: indeed it's in the same class

Comment: just Dim instructions As String = encryption in CallResults then.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable `text` at class-level:

```
Dim text As String

Sub encryption

   text = wraper.DecryptData(ciphertext)

End sub

Public Function CallResults() As String

   Dim instructions As String = text
   Return instructions

End function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a Module to the project that has the text variable declared in it (variable is global to the project.

However it would be better design to have the function accept a variable that it can act upon:

```
Public Function CallResults(Dim text As String)

   Dim instructions As String = text
   Return instructions

End function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function CallResults() As String

Dim instructions As String = encryption '//'text' isn't being recognised
Return instructions

End function
```

would do it. @Ahmed Salman Tahir's answer would be more efficient if you are getting it more than once as it would cache the result of encryption.